# have two actions for one button

Tags: android, barcode-scanner, keycode

I want have tow keyevent in one button

```
case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:        
  Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");<<
  intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
  startActivityForResult(intent, 0);           
  finish();          
  return true;
```

and

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity2.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();`
```

Comment: I ned to be in application scan and with the the same button go in other activity

Comment: There is method to start multiple activities together [startActivities](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivities(android.content.Intent[]))

Comment: you can make a condition check for this . If condition is true open one activity and if not open another

Answer (score 0):

Let's first think about user of your app, but not about app itself. In order to avoid misunderstanding in usage of your app I suggest you, as variant, to implement `AlertDialog` in this case (may be custom `AlertDialog`).

Some user pushes the button and `AlertDialog` appears with title, for example, "Choose the action!" and message that describes options for the user. For Positive button assign "Scan", for Negative button assign those keyword that exactly gives the user understandable choice (in your case, it's redirecting to an other activity), and for Nuetral button assign "Cancel" (you have to give the user choice not to do anything).

If my suggestion will help you it will be good.